# Static Text Color

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have written Following code which will apply color to all static text in one window, but 
I want to apply **two different colors** in **one window** like `ID:1234` where `ID` is another color and `1234` will be different color in one window. How can I do this? here is what i have done:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:

    SetBkColor( hdc, COLORREF( :: GetSysColor( COLOR_3DFACE) ) );    
    //sets bckcolor of static text same as window color

    if ( ( HWND ) lParam == GetDlgItem( hWnd, IDC_PID) ) 
    {
    SetTextColor( ( HDC ) wParam, RGB( 250, 50, 200));
    return ( BOOL ) CreateSolidBrush ( GetSysColor( COLOR_3DFACE) );
    }

    break;
```

Comment: You should create 2 static controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. Your code looks pretty much ok. One point worth noting is that you are responsible for cleaning up resources that you allocate. With the code above you are leaking the `HBRUSH` object created through a call to `CreateSolidBrush`. Since you don't need a custom brush you should rather be using [GetSysColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144927.aspx).

As a matter of taste I would filter on the control ID rather than its window handle using [GetDlgCtrlID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478.aspx). Incorporating the changes your code should look like this:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    switch ( GetDlgCtrlID( (HWND)lParam ) )
    {
    case IDC_PID:
        //sets bckcolor of static text same as window color
        SetBkColor( (HDC)wParam, COLORREF( GetSysColor( COLOR_3DFACE ) ) );    
        SetTextColor( (HDC)wParam, RGB( 250, 50, 200) );
        return (INT_PTR)GetSysColorBrush( COLOR_3DFACE );

    default:
        // Message wasn't handled -> pass it on to the default handler
        return 0;
    }
```